# UIWebView Delegates

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

In my iOS application I have found huge memory usage on presenting a UIWebView. I am trying to implement a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` delegate method. So, what is best practice for watching for memory warnings with a UIWebView?

Here is the code. The problem is that it is not catching the memory warnings which makes me think I am implementing the delegate wrong.

```
class SigninViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
  var appname: String = ""
  var webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
  let appManager = AppManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let address = "https://google.com"
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: address)!))
    webView.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(webView)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    webView.reload()
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Maybe your app didn't receive memory warning. In the simulator you can trigger a memory warning.

Comment: didReceiveMemoryWarning is not a UIWebView delegate. It is a UIViewController delegate.